# Downloading Large AGOL hosted data with attachments

Tags: arcgis-online, file-geodatabase, download

We have a large data collection project with attachments, and have gotten to the point where the data can no longer be downloaded as a file geodatabase without timing out (it can be downloaded as a shapefile).

Is there a method other than the below or downloading it in separate chunks to get a large dataset from AGOL as a file geodatabase?

**Trying these workarounds:**

[Unable to export a large hosted feature service with attachments to a file geodatabase from a REST endpoint](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000015786)

[Unable to export a feature layer with attachments from ArcGIS Online for Organizations to a file geodatabase](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012336)

[Download attachments from a hosted feature service](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012232)

**Results in the following:**

arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.The object has been deleted and is no longer valid.ERROR: code:504, Your request has timed out., Proxy server got bad address from remote server (verify the server is running).Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).

OR

[image]

Comment: how many features are you trying to export with attachments?

Comment: the three datasets are ~200,000, 25,000, and 200,000. They are likely going to grow by 50% at least as it is an ongoing collector project

Comment: Thanks for the info, we do have some improvements for this issue coming in the updating coming  this month. I'll post an update when this rolls out for you to check it out.

Comment: Can you try exporting again? We have recently pushed an update out and would like to know if you are still seeing the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I believe we had success with the smallest of the three, and are currently testing the other two. Will update once it resolves

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem - downloading smaller feature layers as FGDBs via Python arcgis.gis module works fine but large feature layers with attachments are failing.

Answer (score 0):

I received an update from my Esri distributor on how to handle similar situation as I was having the download timeouts in AGOL, Pro and at the REST endpoint. I was trying to export a table with 30,000 attachments.

```
Accessing the tokens in ArcGIS Online is short-lived and can only be used for about 30 minutes. Therefore, about 30 minutes after starting a Create Replica operation from the REST endpoint of a large hosted feature layer (or any other operation done from REST that lasts longer than 30 minutes), the error message about the token will appear.
 
In order to continue viewing the job status and download the result, you will need to generate a new token, copy it and paste it into the URL of the Create Replica Status page.
 
Can you please follow the steps below and see whether it can resolve the issue?
•   Go back to the tab with the hosted feature layer's item details page in ArcGIS Online.
•   Refresh the page. This will generate a new token.
•   Click "View" next to the service URL on the item details page to open the REST endpoint in a new tab
•   Right-click the name of the feature service and select "Open link in new tab". This will allow you to copy the token used to access the REST endpoint.
•   Copy the token from the end of the URL
•   Go back to the tab with the Create Replica Status page displaying the invalid token message
•   Delete the old token from the end of the URL and paste the new token
•   Press enter to reload the page with the new token
•   The Create Replica Status page appears again
•   Once the job is completed, click the result URL to download the result.
```

The result was successful and I was able to download the dataset following these steps.